# White space of responsive iframe is not getting removed using jquery

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, iframe, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap's responsive embed to embed iframe. However, I require that if the iframe is empty (i.e when `src` is empty string), it gets hidden. However, although iframe gets hidden when there's no file to show, but still the white space persists.

Code-snippet for responsive-embed:

```
<div class="row" id="responsive-iframe">
    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9" id="iframe-embed">
        <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="" id="iframe" ></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

Code-snippet for hiding it using jquery:

```
<script>
   $(function() {
        $('#iframe').load(function() {            
          if($.trim($(this).contents().find("body").html()) == "") {
            $('#responsive-iframe').css("display", "none");
          }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I also tried to change iframe's display property to `display: none;`, after reading it might work but still it fails.

Edit: Complete code- https://www.bootply.com/sahildhawan22/ygaJiHuKGg

Answer (score 1):

> if the iframe is empty (i.e when src is empty string), it gets hidden.
>
> the only way to know whether the student has uploaded the resume, is by knowing if src of iframe is an empty string or not

Don't test in `$.load()`. You can just test to see if `src` is an empty string.

```js
$(function() {
  if($('#iframe').attr('src').trim() == '') {
    $('#responsive-iframe').css("display", "none");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    asdf
  </div>
  <div class="row" id="responsive-iframe">
    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9" id="iframe-embed">
        <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="" id="iframe" ></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    bar
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: White space still remains @MichaelCoker

Comment: @sahildhawan does it remain in my demo? I'm not seeing it.

Comment: Yes your code works here, but when I do it in mine, it doesn't. Should I share the whole code? @michelcoker

Comment: https://www.bootply.com/sahildhawan22/ygaJiHuKGg

Here's  my complete code. @michaelcoker

Comment: For some reason, this is not working when I write code in Sublime and open it in Chrome and I'm going crazy. @michaelcoker

Answer (score 0):

I don't think .load event will trigger if you don't set the src property

Comment: So then how could this be achieved?

Comment: leave the code like you have it now... but there must be a place where you set the src? in that place do a `$('#responsive-iframe').css("display", "none");` if there is no src... is difficult without seeing the rest of the code

Comment: Actually, I'm making a recruitment website for my college and what I'm trying to do is that if the student doesn't add a resume, the 16*9 space gets hidden. I'm fetching the resume's URL from database and the only way to know whether the student has uploaded the resume, is by knowing if src of iframe is an empty string or not.